# Show loading image when the page is loading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show loading image while my page is loading after I click on the link to that page. My page is attached to a master page.

I have displayed the loading image on preinit event of page and hide it at the end of page load, but it doesn't display for normal pages and for heavy pages for example which displays Google Maps etc., the image gets displayed for a fraction of second and then hides.

```
  protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Popupshow", "showMessage();", true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Popuphide", "hideMessage();", true);
    }
```

I want the loading image to get displayed from the moment I click on the link of that page until it loads completely.

Comment: The preinit and the end of page, are done together on code behind and before the page is render - you need to use javascript to show what you ask for. And there are all ready many libraries that do that.

Comment: I have put the code what i am using

Comment: as I say, this code is run on code behind, did not matter where you place that code that renders on page - they render at the same time. Find some direct javascript library that do what you look for, and forget the code behind for that.